# how to write it in generics way?

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface, `Parseable`. in which I have method which should return the object of implementing method. Say,

```
P1 implements Parseable {
    P1 fromJson(JSONObject){}
}
```

it is giving unsafe type warning with this below signature. how can I fix it?

`<T> T fromJson(JSONObject)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the interface itself generic instead of the method.

Declare `Parseable` as :

```
public interface Parseable<T> {
    public T fromJson(JSONObject obj);
}
```

And `P1` :

```
public class P1 implements Parseable<P1> {
    @Override
    public P1 fromJson(JSONObject obj){}
}
```

Comment: is there a way to restrict T to be the type of implementing class itself ? I mean, "T" could be anything other than P1 also

Comment: @ay89 What restrictions do you have in mind? You can restrict T to extend some base class or implement some interface.

Comment: in above case, I want generic type of P1 to be P1 itself.

Comment: @ay89 Are you talking about the generic type parameter of the interface Parseable or the class P1? P1 is not generic, and it implements `Parseable<P1>`.

Answer (score 2):

Well. The interface needs to look as

```
public interface Parseable<T> {
    T fromJson(JSONObject json);
}
```

And your class looks as following:

```
public class P1 implements Parseable<P1> {
    @Override public P1 fromJson(JSONObject json) { ... }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to restrict T to be the type of implementing class itself ? I mean, "T" could be anything other than P1 also.

BTW,  +1 for extra formatting ;)

Comment: If you want to express that restriction in the interface, then there is no way. And I don't see a reason for that. You easily can write a `class A implements Parseable<B>` if it fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface Parseable<T> {
    T fromJson(JSONObject js);
} 

P1 implements Parseable<P1> {
    P1 fromJson(JSONObject js) { ... }
}
```